# Feels like Ubuntu 23.10 doesn't deliver full power through USB

Tags: usb, dell, xps

Got a Dell XPS-17 running with Ubuntu 23.10, and every time I plug in my phone, it's in slow charge, which results in my phone losing power when I'm using data sharing.

I'm using a USB C/Thunderbolt port with a compatible cable that works well with quick charging from other power sources.

Any way for me to check this, please? Thanks !

Comment: Try different USB ports. Different ports may have different characteristics on many motherboards. The easiest way to "check" is by using your phone.

Comment: Buy a powered USB hub.

Comment: Do you connect using a USB-C port? What cable do you use?

Comment: @user535733 All USB ports are behaving the same way, the 4 of them.

Comment: @vidarlo USB-C Thunderbolt port, compatible cable (that works well with speed charge from different power sources)

Comment: @Kalytis Thanks :) I've added the information to the question. For future use, please [edit] new information into the question :)